# BackgroundTask not stopping when application comes foreground in ios

Tags: iphone, ios5, background-process

I am using beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler to get 10 minutes extra time for the application to run in background. But I need to stop this background task if the application comes foreground within the provided 10 minutes of time. My code is as follows

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
   {
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^ {
    NSLog(@"invalidate back task in didenter %@",[application backgroundTimeRemaining]);
     if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {  
         [application  endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
         bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
     }

}];

//Background tasks require you to use asyncrous tasks
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"\n\nRunning in the background inside DidEnterBackground %f!\n\n", [application backgroundTimeRemaining]);
    while ([application backgroundTimeRemaining] > 1.0) {
        NSLog(@"\n\nRunning in background %f!\n\n", [application backgroundTimeRemaining]);
        sleep(5);
    }
    [application endBackgroundTask: bgTask]; 
     bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;        
});
 }
```

And when app comes foreground I am ending background task like this

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
 {
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
     bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
  }
```

bgTask is declared globally in .h file. When app goes foreground its still running the background task with showing backgroundTimeRemaining as a long integer value. I am not getting how to stop the background task please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Are you testing on real device? As code looks good

Comment: yes I am testing it with real device itself.

Comment: Why are you using sleep in the main thread, it doesn't look to be right, try `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)` instead.

Comment: sleep() is just to call the while loop every 5 seconds and I used dispatch_get_global_queue too its also gives the same problem